# Install conda package manually Databricks ML runtime

Tags: python, bash, conda, azure-databricks, facebook-prophet

I have a Databricks ML Runtime cluster. I am trying to install fbprophet library using cluster init_script. I am following the example in the Databricks documentation.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
. /databricks/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda info --envs
conda activate /databricks/python
conda install -y --offline /dbfs/conda_packages/linux-64/fbprophet.tar.bz2
```

But the init_script logs show that it cannot activate conda env,  and cannot locate package from given path.

```
: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
bash: line 2: /databricks/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
: No such file or directory
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: unrecognized arguments: --envs

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.



PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - /dbfs/conda_packages/linux-64/fbprophet.tar.bz2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Can you please guide me what is wrong with the script, and how can I install the conda package from a path on DBFS.

Or is there any other way I can install conda packages. Because if I try to install using UI, or library API, it fails to install fbprophet package.

Regards

Comment: Did you ever get this working?